# I made a comment and then later realized it was wrong; How do I make sure not to annoy the person I replied to?

Tags: discussion, comments, notifications, deleted-comments

I made a comment asking if something was correct (*@user shouldn't it be foo not bar?*) then later realized that I was an idiot and they were completely correct. So, my first thought was to delete the comment. However, then both the post owner and the person whom I @ mentioned have a notification for a nonexistent comment. I have had this happen to me and found it very annoying, and would like to avoid doing it to other people, what should I do? Leaving the comment there seems either detrimental or useless, since I know it's wrong and anyone answering the question (*shouldn't it be...*) will be wasting their time. Yet if I delete it, it's annoying. What should I do?

Edit: @PolyGeo recommended I create another comment explaining the situation (*ignore previous comment, I was wrong*) and then delete both comments. This is a possible solution, and if others agree then I will mark PolyGeo's answer as accepted and start doing this. However, the problems I see with this solution are:

- Notifications only display part of the comment. While I'm pretty sure the ignore-my-previous-comment comment would fit into the amount, it may not if I also feel the need to explain why I was wrong or whatever else may come up.
- Creating a comment with the intent to immediately delete it feels hacky and possibly unethical.
- I'm not even sure if it works. It would be quite reasonable for the Stack Exchange system to not notify someone of a comment that would seem to be a mistake. I would take the same action (post and immediately delete) if I accidentally made a comment on the wrong post for whatever reason, in which case it would make sense not to notify anybody.

Comment: Your comments won't persist as notifications as they're deleted. There's a window in there, IIRC... or we possibly remove them entirely. I don't recall off-hand, and unfortunately can't dig quite at the moment.

Comment: @AdamLear there's a window, but in my experience it's very short -- minutes at most, definitely not hours.  A still-pending notification for a deleted comment gets removed.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I meant more for the "create a comment with an explanation and immediately delete it" case. That's not going to work.

Comment: @AdamLear oh, I thought you were saying not to worry about the *original* comment (just delete it and move on).  Yeah, the "ignore that other comment" trick probably doesn't work.

Comment: Another way, if the user got 20+ rep, is invite the user to a chat room, and explain in there. He will get notification about the chat room, and it won't clutter the post itself.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're overthinking it. Just delete the comment.

Answer (score 8):

I would comment along the lines of:

> Please ignore my comment - I was wrong

then a little later delete the wrong comment, and then delete the comment apologizing for it.

Comment: This option passed through my mind when I started writing this but was forgotten by the time I'd written everything else, see my edit.